# tikz foreach floor function

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, pgfmath

It seems that in a tikz-foreach-loop mathematical expressions are not evaluated correctly:

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \c [count=\i] in {0,1,...,{floor(9/4)}}
\node at (\i,0) {\c};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This yields the strange output:

```
0 1 ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Please EDIT to show code, which compiles. By doing so you also show us an important detail: your preamble. Thanks

Comment: @MS-SPO done...

Comment: Please search here for floor. As far as I can see, it‘s not intended to calculate, which would require a missing library. Also have a look at https://tikz.dev/math-parsing#autosec-7653 in case you have to dive a little inti tikz internals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- use `\pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{floor(9/4)}` to save the result as `\n`
- `\n` can than be used as upper limit of the for loop

#### Code

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{floor(9/4)}
    \foreach \c [count=\i] in {0,1,...,\n}
    \node at (\i,0) {\c};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks! The other answer is equally nice, but I can accept only one.

Comment: This should also work without loading `\usetikzlibrary{calc}`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Oh, right. I removed it.

Answer (score 7):

The parser trips over the fact that the `floor` starts with a letter, and hence doesn't find the `floor(9/4)` to be a numeric.

If you add `parse=true` to `\foreach`'s options list, and prefix the `floor` expression with a number such that `\foreach` actually thinks that's a number, you get what you wanted (without a user facing temporary assignment):

```
\documentclass[border=3.14,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \c [count=\i,parse=true] in {0,1,...,1*floor(9/4)}
  \node at (\i,0) {\c};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although, I like this answer a lot, I decided to accept the other answer. Thank you!